# Wanhao Duplicator i3 Mk2 Firmware Update

Tags: firmware

I have a Wanhao Duplicator i3 Plus Mk2. Its auto-leveling never worked properly since I bought it a year or two ago. I decided to upgrade the firmware to try and solve this problem. Unfortunately, I did not know I had a Mk2 when I started this process (I'm a photographer, it is only a Mk2 when it says so on the Camera housing which is seemingly not the case here, you needed to be fortunate to know it is a Mk2 if it has a Z probe). As such, I uploaded the wrong motherboard and LCD firmware (for i3 Plus not i3 Plus Mk2). When I switched on and tried to level, it started driving the nozzle into the bed which in retrospect is to be expected as the firmware is looking for a switch, not a probe. Once I realised what the problem was, I uploaded the Mk2 firmware but it seems uploading the non-Mk2 firmware has confused something somewhere so I can't get it to even be a printer anymore. The LCD is all mixed up with menus over one another and the printer does not react to anything. I tried to format the LCD with the image and procedure on Wanhao's site but this merely seems to exacerbate the problem.

Can anyone please guide me on how to start fresh and get the printer and LCD firmware restored so at least I have something resembling a printer again. The Wanhao customer support has been all but helpful and I've abandoned that channel as they simply email me the same firmware I already downloaded and used to get into this mess.

Comment: A quick Google search shows that there are multiple issues with updating to [new firmware](https://www.wanhao3dprinter.com/FAQ/ShowArticle.asp?ArticleID=79) for printer and LCD (these are separate firmwares!). Useful links are [this one](https://3dprinterwiki.info/wanhao-i3-plus-documentation-factory-files/) and [this one](https://github.com/andrivet/Duplicator-i3-Plus-firmware-collection) which have support for the MkII. Try if that works and update the question accordingly. Did you upload a hex file, or used PlatformIO or ArduinoIDE?

Comment: I uploaded a hex file. I will try and pursue the ArduinoIDE path as I have experience with that for Arduino boards.

Comment: Try to disconnect the display if you go down the Arduino route and see if you get it running while connected to serial (USB) and Pronterface for instance. When pursuing the Arduino route, be sure to send `M502` and `M500` after the flash to the printer to get the values from the firmware and overwrite the current stuff in the EEPROM.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was resolved with the help of comments above.

> A quick Google search shows that there are multiple issues with updating to [new firmware](https://www.wanhao3dprinter.com/FAQ/ShowArticle.asp?ArticleID=79) for printer and LCD (these are separate firmwares!). Useful links are [this one](https://3dprinterwiki.info/wanhao-i3-plus-documentation-factory-files/) and [this one](https://github.com/andrivet/Duplicator-i3-Plus-firmware-collection) which have support for the MkII.
> ...
> Try to disconnect the display if you go down the Arduino route and see if you get it running while connected to serial (USB) and Pronterface for instance. When pursuing the Arduino route, be sure to send `M502` and `M500` after the flash to the printer to get the values from the firmware and overwrite the current stuff in the EEPROM.

I downloaded the Mk2 firmware from [here](https://github.com/andrivet/Duplicator-i3-Plus-firmware-collection/blob/master/Wanhao-i3-Plus-Mark-II-Firmware-v1.02.zip) and then used the normal Wanhao procedure to update both the motherboard and LCD and this left me with a working printer afterwards. Why the firmware downloaded from Wanhao's own site does not work is a mystery.